# Adding classes for CSS styling in AM Charts v4

Tags: amcharts

Is there a way to add classes to elements in AMChart **version 4**, like it was in the previous version? 
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/css-class-names/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is!

```js
am4core.options.autoSetClassName = true;
```

Here's a fork of our ["Pie Chart With Legend" demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-chart-with-legend/) with CSS classes enabled:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/393e251b5655b64cb1e567848aa243c3

You can see that the SVG Elements now has CSS classes for its own amCharts Class as well as those it inherits from starting with `amcharts-`. So e.g. a [`Slice`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/slice/) extends `Container`, so it will have CSS classes `amcharts-Slice` and `amcharts-Container`, e.g.:
[image: screenshot of an amCharts PieChart Slice being inspected in a developer toolbar]